# Internal Implementation of ServerSocket.accept() method?

Tags: java, c#, operating-system, serversocket

Everyone is aware of socket programming in java. we write a code as below:

```
 ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
 Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
```

We know that we create object of serverSocket and next we write `serverSocket.accept();` code to receive client request. we know that `serverSocket.accept();` wait until new request comes.

but my question is : what `serverSocket.accept();` method does internally? might be is running in while loop ? how server identify that any new request is came to serve ?  what is the internal implmentation of `serverSocket.accept();` method?  Any One has idea about this?

Comment: You can go inside that method and see. You can go line by line with debugger too.

Comment: Why is this tagged c# also? I guess the "internal" functionality depends on the OS if not the System architechture.

Comment: Because I use C# and Java. both are same in major cases related to their functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, the `ServerSocket.accept()` ultimately (in native code) does an `accept` syscall (see `man 2 accept`) which blocks waiting for a suitable incoming connection.

There is no `while` loop in the Java code or in the native code.  I've no idea what happens inside the Linux kernel, but at that point this is no longer a Java question.

---

The same would probably apply for Java on Windows, and for C# or any other programming language that you cared to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this by your own.

```
public Socket accept() throws IOException {
    if (isClosed())
        throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
    if (!isBound())
        throw new SocketException("Socket is not bound yet");
    Socket s = new Socket((SocketImpl) null);
    implAccept(s);
    return s;
}
```

How [accept()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html#accept%28%29) works?

Comment: I know above code available in ServerSocket class. my question is how internally works? I'm looking for in-depth answer